# IntelliJ Ideas, how to jump to the definition and jump back?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

On Mac, how to jump to the definition of a function and jump back to the previous position in IntelliJ Ideas, with keymap preference Mac OS X 10.5 +?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> to go to the definition, <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> to go back.

Answer (score 1):

These are the default keymap settings for **Mac OS X 10.5 +**, when you check from **settings -> Keymap**

- Quick definition - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> / <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>

[image]

- Go back - <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> / <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> / Mouse Button4 Click

[image]

You can change/add your own short cut from there too. :))